# How do you remove the title in the banner from the ESRI geoportal extension?

Tags: geoportal

I would like to remove the catalog.site.title text from the banner area in the geoportal page. However, I would still like to keep the title of the page in the browser bar/window.

Does anyone know in which file the catalog.site.title is located for just the banner text? If I remove the text from the catalog.site.title from the site resources in the gpt.properties file the banner title and browser title are replaced with 
`???catalog.site.title`.

[image: Title to remove and title to keep]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Like Brad](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16626/how-do-you-remove-the-title-in-the-banner-from-the-esri-geoportal-extension/16631#16631), I don't see the banner text either, but for future edification:

in \Tomcat\webapps\geoportal\catalog\skins\tiles\banner.jsp, comment out or remove out the .getSiteTitle line (line 21 for me).  Mine looks like the following.

```
<div id="gptTitle">
    <!--<%=com.esri.gpt.framework.jsf.PageContext.extract().getSiteTitle()%>-->
</div>
```

That will remove the banner text but the page title will still be bound to `catalog.site.title` in `gpt.properties`.

This is using Geoportal 1.1.

Comment: that is great to know.

Comment: It's true that on the page that you're seeing, our live site, it doesn't show up. However, I had installed it on my local machine to make changes to the page so that I didn't have to change the live site. When I installed it I copied everything I had on the server, including the banner.jsp file. For whatever reason it was showing it, even though it was commented out. I'm not real sure what went wrong here, as it makes no sense what-so-ever. Thank you, as that helped me find it again. All I did was un-comment it out and then re-comment it out again. That fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps just occurring on your domain inside?
I don't see it on the public version.
[image: tabtitle]

[image: don't see it here]

Non-the-less
My location for that title (the one you want to go away) is in the config.xml (flex application) inside my application.
And the other (the one you want to keep is in the default.htm also inside the application folder.

Comment: Thanks Brad, but I'm not using the Flex app on this one.